# Geometry outputs from postgis and sequelize

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have looked through the docs and have not found what I am looking for... could be me. I want to know what options I have through sequelize for parsing postgres geom columns. I have found geom.coordinates but do we have any other options? WKT? GeoJSON? I know I can do raw queries but I wanted to keep in the ORM if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiarize with `sequelize` but if you have problem with postgres geometry type you can create a string field on your table and use it in your ORM instead

Use [**ST_AsText()**](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsText.html) function to store a text representation of your geometry

> text ST_AsText(geometry g1);
>
> text ST_AsText(geography g1);